# Is there way to specify expiry when creating a celery task?

Tags: celery

Specifically I use `shared_task` decorator to create a celery task.
I tried the obvious `@shared_task(expires=3)` but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to tell this task is supposed to expire ** seconds after it is received as you can do with `apply_async` in calling time?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about shared_task, but in Celery 5.2.7 at least, you can pass an `expires` parameter to `@app.task`.

```
from myapp.celery import app as celery_app

@celery_app.task(expires=60)
def my_task(...
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this should help

```
from tasks import add
result = add.apply_async(args=[10, 10], expires=6000)
```

Also make sure that your producer and consumer machine clocks are in sync. Else use

```
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Etc/UTC'
```

Comment: I know about apply_async. OP asks if there's a way to set expire option to the task itself so that I don't have to worry about expiring whenever I call it.